# php change a string to another and reverse back

Tags: php

How is it possible to change a string to another unique string and reverse it back. Like:

```
$c = H; $d = Z; $a = @;
```

How do I change this string: `cad` to `H@Z` and reverse it back to `cad`

**For example:** if i have a string "`placed`" I want to replace every 
"`a`" with `@`, 
"`c`" with `H`, and 
"`d`" with `Z` 
so that the output will be = `pl@HeZ` and how do I return it to the original string which is "`placed`"

Comment: Are you talking about encoding and decoding?

Comment: You can just redefine the variable on the next line and then redefine again....If you could give more context we could come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: Could you give a little more information? Do you mean you'd want to be able to convert `H@Z` back into the `$c`, `$d`, and `$a` variables?

Comment: @RenjithVR  I just added description to what I want to ask for easy understanding. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Build your character conversion map as an array, indexed by character and value the substitution character, and it will be a lot easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

function encrypt_string($stringToConvert){

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($stringToConvert); $i++){

        switch($stringToConvert[$i]){

            case 'a':
                $stringToConvert[$i] = '@';
                break;
            case 'c':
                $stringToConvert[$i] = 'H';
                break;
            case 'd':
                $stringToConvert[$i] = 'Z';
                break;
            default:

        }
    }

    return $stringToConvert;
}


function decrypt_string($stringToConvert){


    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($stringToConvert); $i++){

        switch($stringToConvert[$i]){

            case '@':
                $stringToConvert[$i] = 'a';
                break;
            case 'H':
                $stringToConvert[$i] = 'c';
                break;
            case 'Z':
                $stringToConvert[$i] = 'd';
                break;
            default:


        }

    }

    return $stringToConvert;
}



$mNormalString = "placed";
$mEncryptedString = encrypt_string($mNormalString);
$mDecryptedString = decrypt_string($mEncryptedString);



echo "My unencrypted string : $mNormalString <br/>";
echo "My encrypted string : $mEncryptedString <br/>";
echo "My decrypted string : $mDecryptedString";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Result :**

[image]

**How :**

We use two functions. **encrypt_string** and **decrypt_string** which both return the encrypted string and decrypted. You will have to put all the cases that you need - for each letter/symbol inside those two funcitons.

However, even though i don't know much about encryption this is just a very simple answer to what you wanted to do. If you want to learn about secured and with the correct way encryption you could search it or even better if someone could comment/edit a reference for that if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks alot @Tony you are marvelous

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the string as you need

```
<?php
function varName($theVar) {  
   $variableName = key($theVar);  
   $variableValue = $theVar[$variableName];  
   echo ('The name of the variable used in the function call was '.$variableName.'<br />');  
   echo ('The value of the variable used in the function call was '.$variableValue.'<br />');  
}
$c = 'H'; $d = 'Z'; $a = '@';

$temp_arr = get_defined_vars ();


$string_val = '';
$original_val = '';

foreach($temp_arr as $key => $temp)
{
  if($key!='_GET' && $key!='_POST' && $key!='_FILES' && $key!='_COOKIE')
  {
    $string_val.=$temp;
    $original_val.=$key;
  }
}

echo $string_val."<br/>".$original_val;

?>
```